# Get shared edges of triangles using their coordinates

Tags: c#

I have a problem. I need to get the count of shared edges of triangles using their coordinates. All the triangles are stored in a list that looks like this:

```
public class TriangleRegistryList
{
    public float x1 { get; set; }
    public float y1 { get; set; }
    public float x2 { get; set; }
    public float y2 { get; set; }
    public float x3 { get; set; }
    public float y3 { get; set; }
    public int ShapeNum { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am using a IEnumerable List to compare everything with K-combinations, but people say to me that it could be way easier using 2 foreach loops. I know what they mean, but how can I check whether the sides are the same?

I also want no doubles or inverted doubles! 
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: `how can I check whether the sides are the same` - if their end points have same coordinates?

Comment: It would be even easier if you stored your triangle as a list of points.

Comment: @GSerg, but I don't know which side has the same edge

Comment: @DourHighArch I have stored them in a list?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk The one where both end points have same coordinates in both triangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the points in array instead of x0, y0... and it would be easy to count it with very short code, with linq instead of loops.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

internal class Polygon
{
    public IReadOnlyList<(int x, int y)> EndPoints { get; }

    public Polygon(params (int, int)[] endPoints) => EndPoints = endPoints;
}

internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var data = new[]
        {
            new Polygon((0,1),(2,3),(4,5)),
            new Polygon((0,1),(2,3),(6,7)),
            new Polygon((0,1),(4,5),(6,7)),
        };

        var shareds = data
            .SelectMany(a => data.Where(b => b != a), (a, b) => (a, b))
            .Count(c => c.a.EndPoints.Count(p1 => c.b.EndPoints.Any(p2 => p1 == p2)) >= 2)
            / 2;

        Console.WriteLine(shareds);  //3
    }
}
```